# KDB select where

Tags: kdb

I have a table

```
t:flip `dt`id`data ! (`d1`d1`d2`d2`d3`d3; 0 1 0 1 0 1; 100 200 100 300 0 200)
```

and from some other query, I have a table

```
s:flip `dt`id ! (`d1`d2`d2`d3; 0 0 1 1)
```

How can I select from t such that it returns all entries where the combination of dt and id are in s, so return

```
flip `dt`id`data ! (`d1`d2`d2`d3; 0 0 1  1; 100 100 300 200)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `in` on table to table ops so just create a table from your required columns in t and use in to search s for the corresponding records. As long as the table columns and types from the left argument and right argument are the same, then `in` will produce a boolean list as expected.

```
q)select from t where ([]dt;id) in s
dt id data
----------
d1 0  100
d2 0  100
d2 1  300
d3 1  200
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well. Just to understand this... this creates a dict and checks if that dict is in the table? Out of curiosity, if it can do that, why cant I do this... "\`dt\`id!(`d1;0j) in s"

Comment: This creates a table from columns dt and id and then applies an in operation to the two tables. With regards to your in question - the interpreter reads from right to left, so what your statement is actually doing is `(\`d1;0j) in s` before anything else (and hence you error). You can run `(\`dt\`id!(\`d1;0j)) in s` successfully.

Comment: ah, thanks. that right to left thing gets me regularly